# wsgi.application failure on install of django-hosts

Tags: django

I'm attempting to install django-hosts.

I've added django-host to my installed apps, added the necessary code at the start and end of the middleware section and I've defined ROOT_HOSTCONF and DEFAULT_HOST as per the instructions located here:

https://django-hosts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I'm now getting the following error when I try to run the server on my local machine:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000002240DA40A60>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 44, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    return import_string(app_path)
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\jason\Desktop\jason\jasonsproject\wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 140, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 37, in load_middleware
    middleware = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_hosts.middleware.HostsRequestMiddlewaremultipledomain'; 'django_hosts.middleware' is not a package

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 140, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\runserver.py", line 27, in get_handler
    handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 65, in get_handler
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 49, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'jasonsproject.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.
```

Any thoughts on what could be going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you added **`django_hosts`** to your `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: Yes I added it :)